# ReactJS conditional display of elements with map function is returning that my object or key is 'undefined'

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

Here I have passed my state from one component to another the same way I've done before. And when I console.log the passed state (before I add the map statement in JSX) I get the object im looking for. But when I go inside the return statement I get "cannot map 'undefined'". And at that point the console.log starts returning as undefined. But before I tried to map over the passed prop the console.log was returning the data.Can anyone help me see what im doing wrong?

```
function Items ({orgList}) {


console.log(orgList.items)

return (
    <>

  {orgList ? 
    <div>
    {orgList.items.map((item, i) => (
        
        <Card key={i} className= "w-100 m-2">
        <CardHeader className="d-flex">
            <p>Hello</p>
        </CardHeader>
        <CardBody>
            <p>The Body</p>
            <Row>
                <Col md="5">
                    <dl>
                        <dt>GroupID</dt>
                        <dd>{item.GroupID}</dd>
                        <dt>Name</dt>
                        <dd>{item.name}</dd>
                    </dl>
                </Col>
            </Row> 
        </CardBody>
    </Card>
        ))}
    </div>
    :
    <div>
    <PageLoadSpinner inProgress={inProgress} />
    </div>
    } 
 </>
)
}
export default Items;**strong text**
```

Here is the parent Component

```
function Orgs () {

const [orgList, setOrgList] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    loadOrgs();
}, []);

const loadOrgs = () => {
    api.MonitoringOrg.list()
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        setOrgList(...orgList, response)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}

return(
   
    <>
     <Items orgList={orgList}/>        
    </>


)

}

export default Orgs;
```

Comment: Can you add the parent component code please

Comment: Yes I have added it to the original question

Comment: Let's test something. Try changing `{orgList ?` to `{orgList ?.items?` and let me know what happens.

Comment: @HarleyLang that fixed my error. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @CourtneyJ I'll provide an answer for why that fixes your error momentarily!

Answer (score 0):

Errors that include `undefined` like the one you are observing likely mean one of two things:

(1) The variable is not defined or accessible to the function. This is not the case in your situation as you have shown that the variable is accessible outside of the scope of your conditional. Or,

(2) The render function has not yet evaluated your variable by the time it gets to rendering. This is likely the case in your situation.

I think the second situation is due to a race condition, and I leave the details of that to someone with better knowledge of the React source code to explain.

An easy way to avoid this situation is to update your conditional with the specific keys you will need. This will help prevent the render function from short circuiting your component. This way, your data will not be called upon if a render proceeds without it being there.

Given in your situation that you are drawing on `orgList.items` in your map function, let's update the code as per the following:

```
function Items ({orgList}) {


console.log(orgList.items)

return (
    <>

  {orgList?.items?             {/* <------ update this line as seen here */}
    <div>
    {orgList.items.map((item, i) => (
        
        <Card key={i} className= "w-100 m-2">
        <CardHeader className="d-flex">
            <p>Hello</p>
        </CardHeader>
        <CardBody>
            <p>The Body</p>
            <Row>
                <Col md="5">
                    <dl>
                        <dt>GroupID</dt>
                        <dd>{item.GroupID}</dd>
                        <dt>Name</dt>
                        <dd>{item.name}</dd>
                    </dl>
                </Col>
            </Row> 
        </CardBody>
    </Card>
        ))}
    </div>
    :
    <div>
    <PageLoadSpinner inProgress={inProgress} />
    </div>
    } 
 </>
)
}
export default Items;
```

Comment: @CourtneyJ did this help solve your question? If so, I would greatly appreciate it if this can be accepted as the answer and if this did not help, please let me know how I can improve this answer.